# Ruby gem for parsing embed video links/urls, http links, images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, rubygems

Does anyone know of a parser gem/library that works with Rails which parses input from given by a user just like Facebook does? So if I were to just post a youtube link into a textarea and run it through the parser library then it will provide an output which features the HTML for displaying the video (even some basic HTML that JavaScript can hook into). Same goes for links, email links and images.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non free option: [embedly](http://blog.embed.ly/embedlys-gem).  Looks to be of high quality from the 3rd party articles I've read.  Open source option: [ohembedr](https://github.com/benofsky/ohembedr/).